# Show author of an entry in the guestbook with two tables (myphpadmin)

Tags: php

I have two tables in my database. One stores the users who register on the website and the other stores the entries in the guestbook. Now I would like to match the UserID with Name to the author via Join. If a contribution was written anonymously, the name should be replaced by Anonymous.
How can I do this in the smartest way? 
I know I could do anything on one table, but I'd like to do it on two for testing purposes.

Login:

```
<?php
  include ('dbconnection.php');

  if(isset($_POST['absenden'])):
    $benutzername = strtolower($_POST['benutzername']);
    $passwort = $_POST['passwort'];
    $passwort = md5($passwort);

    $search_user = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE benutzername = ? AND passwort = ?");
    $search_user->bind_param('ss',$benutzername,$passwort);
    $search_user->execute();
    $search_result = $search_user->get_result();

  if($search_result->num_rows == 1):
    $search_object = $search_result->fetch_object();

    $_SESSION['user'] = $search_object->id;
    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); 
  else:
    echo 'Deine Angaben sind leider nicht korrekt!';
  endif;
endif;
?>
```

Guestbook:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php
        session_start();
        include ('dbconnection.php');
        include 'checklogin.php';
        include 'head_nav.html';
        include 'kontakt.html';

    ?>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="betreff" placeholder="Betreff?"><br>
            <textarea name="nachricht" placeholder="Ihre Nachricht!"></textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Absenden!"><br>
        </form>
    <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])):
                $betreff = $_POST['betreff'];
                $nachricht = $_POST['nachricht'];
                $absenden = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO kontakt (betreff,nachricht,datum) VALUES (?,?,NOW())");
                $absenden->bind_param('ss',$betreff,$nachricht);
                $absenden->execute();
            endif;

            $abfrage = $db->query("SELECT * FROM kontakt ORDER BY datum DESC");
            echo  'Es wurden '.$abfrage->num_rows.' Nachrichten gefunden!<br>';

            while($ausgabe = $abfrage->fetch_object()){
                echo '
                <b>Betreff:</b> '.$ausgabe->betreff.' <br>
                <b>Nachricht:</b><br> '.$ausgabe->nachricht.' <br>
                <hr>
                ';
            }

            include 'footer.html';

    ?>            
    </body>
</html>
```

Table users:

```
ID (Primary Key, type: int, attribute: unsigned, extra: auto_increament)
benutzername (Index, type: varchar(255)) 
passwort (type: varchar(255))
created_at (timestamp)
updated_at (timestamp)
```

Table guestbook:

```
ID (Primary Key, type: int, extra: auto_increament)
Topic (type: archer(255))
Message (type: text)
date (type: datetime)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a separate column in your guestbook table for a user id then when you are saving the guestbook posts also store the user id you already have in your $_SESSION variable.

### Edit

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])):
    $betreff = $_POST['betreff'];
    $nachricht = $_POST['nachricht'];
    $user = $_SESSION['user'];
    $absenden = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO kontakt (betreff,nachricht,[new column],datum) VALUES (?,?,?,NOW())");
    $absenden->bind_param('ss',$betreff,$nachricht,$user);
    $absenden->execute();
endif;
```

### Edit 2

Change:

```
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
```

to:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    $user = $_SESSION['user'];
}else{
    $user = 'Anonymous'; // or guest or whatever you want
}
```

Comment: I have added UserID to the guestbook table. What would your suggestion look like in the code?

Comment: You just need to insert the $_SESSION variable into that table when it is created. See edit above

Comment: and where do i define that if a user is not logged in, the name is displayed "anonymous"?

Comment: So instead of storing a user ID you could just store whatever you want, see edit above again

Comment: Or if you have set up the table to accept an 'int' you can just say '0' instead of 'anon' and then when you are displaying the posts you can say if the user id is 0 display anonymous else query users DB for user name

Comment: i once adopted the code as you said it. now the problem is that he only lets me make an entry in the guestbook if i'm NOT logged in. if i'm logged in, nothing happens as if there was no entry. //EDIT: there is also no entry in the database

Comment: //EDIT2: Nvm, no guestbook entry will be accepted anymore